# Emacs experts : is possible connect f# intellisense command line tool with emacs?

Tags: emacs, f#, intellisense

I love emacs, I've used this for the latest years and when I need open an ide, although Visual studio is an amazing ide, I feel limited and it's very heavy weight for my old computer, I'm using emacs for f# although I feel than emacs is not so appropiate for a static type language, I've seen than c# has an intellisense in emacs

http://code.google.com/p/idebridge/

I'ven't tried this yet, but I think than an autocomplete for f# must be simplest because f# has a cross package with an f# intellisense thought for be adapted in other text editor

http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=fsharp%20intellisense%20tool&referringTitle=Home

I don't know much about emacs programming but it should not be so complex, only connect emacs with the script and share information..

note: I know than in the past there was a try for implement intellisense in emacs
http://laurent.le-brun.eu/site/index.php/2011/02/14/61-fsharp-intellisense-in-emacs-in-progress

I've tried install it but the little program works only with a really old fsharp power pack, it hasn't been update for long time, I can't communicate with the author and the code is close, I don't know if the original author was using the fsintellisense...

I don't know if it's the best place for ask this, but I hope than many people than read this post show the same interest in emacs-fsharp and anyone know how hard can be implement this in emacs or has the interest in do it...thanks!!

Comment: Atleast I thought, static typed languages are easy to parse with Emacs CEDET.

Comment: Potentially you can use this tool to provide completions for Emacs's CEDET - see, for example, to Clang support in CEDET. For more details, please look to cedet site & mailing list

Comment: It looks like that was written by @TomasPetricek.  He's on StackOverflow--may see this question.  You might also try tweeting him: tomaspetricek.  I'm surprised the source code isn't on CodePlex.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the source code for fsintellisense *is* available.

http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4d371abd932f

Click on Samples then Compiler and then the source is under fsintellisense.  I don't think this is completely answering your question but this seems too much information to put in to a comment.

Comment: yes, the fsintellisense is available, but the implementation in emacs did for lauren is not :( ...he only post a executable but this require a really old power pack and he said it need many improves.... http://laurent.le-brun.eu/site/index.php/2011/02/14/61-fsharp-intellisense-in-emacs-in-progress

Comment: Oh--ok. Misunderstood your comment. But I'd be very surprised if the requirement for the old PowerPack came from the emacs side so I would think probably you want to figure out where the dependency is in the FS code and attack it from there first.

Comment: there is a fork (rewrite?) of that tool that doesn't have any powerpack dependency and works with .Net 4.0 https://github.com/fahadsuhaib/fsharp/tree/master/samples/FSI.Intellisense

Answer (score 0):

This has now been implemented and is available at https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/tree/master/emacs